# bootstrap:checkbox not returning value

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using iphone style checkbox with below code. 
It is showing properly and working fine. But when i submit the form it is not sending any value.

```
 <div class = "col-sm-6 col-xs-6"  >Gender</div>
<label id="sliderLabel">
    <input id="gender" name="gender" ng-model="formData.gender" type="checkbox" />
    <span id="slider">
        <span id="sliderOn">Male</span>
        <span id="sliderOff">Female</span>
        <span id="sliderBlock"></span>
    </span>
</label>
```

I am using angular js for client side validation.

Please advise me what am i doing wrong.

Edit:

```
 formApp.controller('formProfile2', function($scope,$http){

      $scope.formData = {};

        $scope.formprofile2 = function() {

          var allData={'formData': $scope.formData, 'uid': uid}
        $http({
              method  : 'POST',
              url     : 'register.php',
              data : allData,
              headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  
          })
```

If i click on anyone then it is returning the data(true/false) but i need to return false if not clicked.

Comment: Please share the code where you submit the data and the html template with the ```<form>``` tag

Comment: added angular code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try to use ng-true-value/ ng-false-value with boolean or any numeric value

```
<input type="checkbox" 
ng-model="checkbox" 
ng-true-value=true 
ng-false-value=false
/>
```

add condition before the pass formData

```
    if(!$scope.formData.gender){
 $scope.formData.gender=false;
}
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working. first i need to place true false under quote. Second thing if i simple submit the form then no value passed. i want unchecked value should passed.

Comment: can you add that condition before the pass formdata to alldata

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox return undefined if you don't check, So you may use a condition before send the HTTP request.